# Go back to second foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net

What is the most elegant way to continue outer loop after one of if statements executed? I know I could use `goto`, however I would like to avoid it.

```
  foreach (var pair in firstStrings)
        {
            foreach (var pair2 in secondStrings)
            {
                if (secondStrings.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
                {
                    LogMessage(
                        pair.Value + " <----------> " + pair2.Value + " On Line " + (int)(pair.Key.Item1 + 1));

                }
                if (!(secondStrings.ContainsKey(pair.Key)))
                {
                    LogMessage(
                        pair.Value + "Missing data " + " on line " + (int)(pair.Key.Item1 + 1) + " in file " + " " +
                        Path.GetFileName(pathTwo));

                }

                if (!(firstStrings.ContainsKey(pair2.Key)))

                    LogMessage(
                        pair2.Value + "Missing data " + " on line " + (int)(pair2.Key.Item1 + 1) + " in file " + " " +
                        Path.GetFileName(pathOne));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whats about `break` in inner loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `break`. It breaks the loop you are in right now.

Plus, in your condition you should use `else if` rather than multiple `if`.

```
foreach (var pair in firstStrings)
{
    foreach (var pair2 in secondStrings)
    {
        if (secondStrings.ContainsKey(pair.Key))
        {
            LogMessage(
                pair.Value + " <----------> " + pair2.Value + " On Line " + (int)(pair.Key.Item1 + 1));

            break;
        }
        else if (!(secondStrings.ContainsKey(pair.Key)))
        {
            LogMessage(
                pair.Value + "Missing data " + " on line " + (int)(pair.Key.Item1 + 1) + " in file " + " " +
                Path.GetFileName(pathTwo));

            break;
        }
        else if (!(firstStrings.ContainsKey(pair2.Key)))
        {
            LogMessage(
                pair2.Value + "Missing data " + " on line " + (int)(pair2.Key.Item1 + 1) + " in file " + " " +
                Path.GetFileName(pathOne));

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for `else` after `break;`

Answer (score 1):

`break;` will in most languages break the inner loop (jump out to outer loop in your case).

Answer (score 1):

The break statement would work, as it only breaks the inner loop, not all loops.